# Массив указателей на структуру

Tags: c, массивы, указатели, динамические-массивы

Добрый вечер. Подскажите как лучше на Си реализовать данную структуру(Массив указателей на структуру, что конкретно в структуре не особо важно). Не получается никак.
И как потом передавать эту структуру через указатели в функцию?
Я пробовал вот так List *str[N], но это никак не передать в функцию, чтоб там изменять

[image: Структура]

Comment: что такое List?

Comment: Ну я так назвал структуру. struct List. Забыл совсем написать. N - define если что

Comment: чтобы не заморачиваться, можно сделать typedef List *Str[N], и в процедуру передавать указатель на этот тип: proc(Str *v);

Comment: Ок щас попробую, спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Эти боковые ветки - что-то вроде

```
struct Node
{
    int a,b;
    Node * next;
}
```

а по вертикали -

```
struct Node* str[N];
```

Т.е. массив указателей на списки.